# Auto complete is not working in my asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

i have the following repository method to search for users containing a search parameter:-

```
public IEnumerable<User> searchusers2(string q)
    {
        return from u in entities1.Users
               where (u.UserID.Contains(q) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(q))
               select u;
           }
```

which is called suing the following action method:-

```
public ActionResult QuickSearch(string term)
       {
           var users = r.searchusers2(term);
           users.Select(a => new { value = a.UserID });
           return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and on the view i have the following code:-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "User", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "searchResults",
   LoadingElementId = "progress"
}))
{

     <input type="text" name="q" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("QuickSearch", "User")" />
     <input type="hidden" name="classid" value="@ViewBag.classid"/>



     <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

the above code is not working but if i change my action method to be as follow (without using a repository to perform the search) then the auto complete will work fine,,, so what might be causing this problem:-

```
public ActionResult QuickSearch(string term)
       {
                                 var users = entities1.Users
               .Where(e => e.UserID.Contains(term))
               .Select(r => new {value = r.UserID });
            return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the repository-version you're returning the whole User object in Json, The `Select` in

```
public ActionResult QuickSearch(string term)
{
           var users = r.searchusers2(term);
           users.Select(a => new { value = a.UserID });
           return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

is doing nothing because you're not storing the returned values, you'll either need to chain the call together, e.g:

```
public ActionResult QuickSearch(string term)
{
           var users = r.searchusers2(term).Select(a => new { value = a.UserID });
           return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

or use a separate variable:

```
public ActionResult QuickSearch(string term)
{
           var users = r.searchusers2(term);
           var values = users.Select(a => new { value = a.UserID });
           return Json(values, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```